# Should I use Kubernetes operator or just kubernetes api to accomplish dynamic Kubernetes pod creation based on user processes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-apiserver, kubernetes-operator

I am developing an architecture. The idea is that I need a running server listening for incoming connects of IOT devices. This node server setup is straight forward and can be an always running process.

down stream from a connected device I am thinking I want to spin up a pod that will have the following characteristics.

1. create node server per client connection request (assuming 1 pod per user)
2. provide ip so websocket/server sent event can connect
3. listen for events from the params setup by the connected device
4. process events business logic.
5. when device disconnects. Disconnect and delete pod instance.

From reading, I am thinking this could be done with the Kubernetes API. Should I do this just with the api or is this really a better abstraction for CRD's managed by an operator interfacing with the Kubernetes api?

I was kind of thinking perhaps this is a durable Function (azure) or long running serverless function (aws).

For my use case, what is the best tooling. Should I just write the operator directly or use something like an operator framework? Or again, is the direct usage of the api good enough for my use case?

I want it to be scalable so that each user connected will spin up a pod for their work cycle.

I could just run 3 long standing running servers but to me that just feels like it is not a scalable solution.

Comment: I'd discourage a pod-per-request or pod-per-user setup.  This scales poorly, and your application will have to manage all of the pods it creates somehow.  It can also take quite a bit of time to create a pod (longer than an interactive HTTP request should normally wait) and this approach can use substantially more resources than a smaller number of shared pods.  Can you just accept the request from the client and handle it directly, scaling your main application pods if needed?

Comment: Hey @DavidMaze you're probably right about the spin up of a pod per user. Here is my issue. Maybe it's just a dumb thing in my thinking. With an api you can call it and send in params. Ok great the question becomes from that are sessions per request - thinking stateless is best. Meaning, does each call hold it's on state with incoming params. That's one thing. So, can I call an api session for an hour or 2 if I need that. So for example think of a chat application and a user session with other users. The users need to be real time for the moment they are in session. Afterwards it can close.

Comment: What I also think is not scalable is having some big arse stream sending in everything and trying to pull data from that stream and funnel it all over the place. The idea for sure is that 1 stream key/stream exists per person. The connection and disconnection key/stream can be universal.   What can I do, if i had just had standing servers pods ready to go, to be context in the server for a user session. /without an api? lol, and then how does that work as a session (not being an api per se.) You see what I mean?